# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1+x^8}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do I integrate $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1+x^8} dx$$

Currently My Brain got blank because there no substitution is working in solving this problem. Even if I try to solve using partial fraction, it takes lots of time.

Please help me in solving this question.

Comment: Partial fractions is the way to go.

Comment: Buy it is very lengthy to solve using partial fraction

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $t=x^2$ to reexpress the integral,

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1+x^8} dx = \frac12 \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+t^4} dt$$

$$=\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\left( \frac{1+t^2}{1+t^4} +\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^4}\right)dt $$
$$=\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\left( \frac{1+\frac{1}{t^2}}{t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}} -\frac{1-\frac{1}{t^2}}{t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}}\right)dt $$
$$=\frac14\int_{0}^{1} \frac{d(t-\frac{1}{t})}{(t-\frac{1}{t})^2+2} 
+\frac14\int_{0}^{1}\frac{d(t+\frac{1}{t})}{2-(t+\frac{1}{t})^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{4\sqrt2} \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(t-\frac{1}{t})\right)_0^1+\frac{1}{4\sqrt2}\coth^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(t+\frac{1}{t})\right)_0^1$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt2}{16}(\pi+2\coth^{-1}\sqrt2)$$